# Is an object captured by closure when its field is used in the closure in c#

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, closures

If an anonymous method captures a field of an object, would that whole object be caputed and not being garbarge collected?

So following is a snippet, what I want to know is whether SessionKeeper will hold the object f as long as the anonymous method is not explicited removed from the list :

```
class Foo
{
    public String State { get; set; }
    public void KeepState()
    {
        SessionKeeper.Singleton.Add(delegate
        {
            //do something with this.State
        });
    }
}

Foo f = new Foo();
f.KeepState();
```

Comment: According to the comment, the closure uses `this`, so that's what will be captured.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If an anonymous method captures a field of an object, would that whole object be caputed and not being garbarge collected?

The question presupposes a falsehood and therefore cannot be sensibly answered. Anonymous methods only "capture" locals, formal parameters and `this`, never fields of classes. Fields of classes, elements of arrays, and so on, are not considered "outer variables" for the purpose of closing over.

Now, if the field is a field *of a local* then *you've used the local*, and the local will be captured. But it would be captured regardless of whether you used it for its fields or not; the fields don't come into it.

Comment: maybe I said it wrong, but how the value will be when the anonymous method get called if object'fields cannot be captured.

Comment: @RussellYan: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Try writing up a small piece of code that illustrates your scenario and post that.

Comment: @RussellYan: `this` counts as an outer variable, so any use of `this` in the closure will capture the variable. Since `this` is immutable, that effectively captures the value. So `this` will then live at least as long as the delegate. The fact that you used a field of `this` is irrelevant; *any* usage of `this` will cause the anonymous function to capture it.